# SSEEmitter in IE not working Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, eventsource

[image]I have implemented this event source .But, its not working on IE as suggested by many i am using

> https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js this
>   pollyfill for IE.

which was suggested by

> [Is there a Microsoft equivalent for HTML5 Server-Sent Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498141/is-there-a-microsoft-equivalent-for-html5-server-sent-events)

In my code where i need this EventSource i have done like this:

```
 require('../../../style/vendors/EventSource.js'); --> In My Import

 ngOnInit() 
  {   
  let es = new   EventSource('http://localhost:8080/api/message');
  }
```

But, again when running on IE i am getting the error what i was getting earlier :

```
"ReferenceError: 'EventSource' is undefined
   at MessageComponent.prototype.ngOnInit (http://localhost:8080/js/app.8c7c223048ac731c6001.js:42531:10)
```

Please suggets me whether am missing anything or the Problem with Pollyfills?

Comment: Why is `.js` file in directory where parent directory is labelled `style`?

Comment: @guest271314 hmmm...just to check my code i placed the .js file inside style folder.

Comment: Have not used ie in some time; have not browsed polyfill code. Have you posted an issue at github repo for the polyfill?

Comment: @guest271314 yes i have posted on Github too but there they have not done with angular 2 . So, asked to ask this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Have not tried angular2 either. Does polyfill define `EventSource` if angular2 is not used?

Comment: @guest271314 i am not sure because i cannot able to find anything related to angular 2. but, from npm we can install the pollyfills https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-source-polyfill . There they have explained it for php. So, i am not geeting any clue whether my code is incorrect or is the problem with pollyfils

Comment: Is `open` event logged at `console` at ie at https://jsfiddle.net/jv04ddLb/?

Comment: @guest271314 i am sorry i did'nt get your question

Comment: Check `console` at jsfiddle at previous comment. Is `open` event of `EventSource` logged at ie?

Comment: @guest271314 yes in chrome its Event
bubbles
:
false
cancelBubble
:
false
cancelable
:
false
composed
:
false
currentTarget
:
EventSource
defaultPrevented
:
false
eventPhase
:
0
isTrusted
:
true
path
:
Array[0]
returnValue
:
true
srcElement
:
EventSource
target
:
EventSource
timeStamp
:
1564.2650000000003
type
:
"open"
__proto__
:
Event But, in IE i am getting SCRIPT5: Access is denied File: show, Line: 1, Column: 1

Comment: Appears to be issue with ie. Though not sure what `Access is denied File` is referencing?

Comment: @guest271314 i am checking with the ACCESS DENIED issue. I'll let you know if i am getting anything on this.

Comment: @guest271314 the ACCESS DENIED is because of the ; in the very 1st line of the JS file i removed the ; and error gone but looks like the retrun is not correct i have attached the pic in(IE) the question plz check.

Comment: "but looks like the retrun is not correct" What do you mean? The jsfiddle was to check if `EventSource` is defined outside of the `javascript` which you are currently using at ie. The issue is not with `EventSource` being `undefined`.

Comment: @guest271314 because its returning null and the output is different from chrome console.

Comment: What is returning null? The issue described at original Question is `EventSource` being `undefined`. If `EventSource` is not `undefined` at linked jsfiddle, where polyfill is defined, the issue appears to be at another portion of `javascript`

Comment: @guest271314 __proto__  do you know how to call this JS file and pass the URL  In order to connected to server? i want to call this js file from other .js file or html page

Comment: Include the polyfill, make certain path to resource at `require()` call is correct

Comment: @guest271314 require is pointing correctly to the path but i guess i cannot able to call the functions inside the EventSource.js  const es = require('../../../style/vendors/EventSource.js'); i am getting the following when i am doing the console.log(es)                                                 ();Object
EventSource
:
(url)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: What do you mean by "call the functions inside the EventSource.js"? What is server response from `'http://localhost:8080/api/message'`?

Comment: @guest271314 i mean to ask how to use this EventSource.js in order to connected to server

Comment: Use `message` event attached to `EventSource` instance to get stream from server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512572/how-to-send-xmlhttprequest-continuously-in-webworker/42513099#42513099

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry to bother you again                                                 i am getting below exception when using es.addEventListner                                                                                TypeError: es.addEventListener is not a function
    at NotificationComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:8425/js/app.1467cfb67d5944de8cd9.js:42536:13)
    at Wrapper_NotificationComponent.ngDoCheck (/NotificationModule/NotificationComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:16:73)

Comment: @guest271314 my implemented code:                                                                                                       const es = require('../../../style/vendors/EventSource.js');
es.EventSource('URL');
es.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
   console.log('event source open')
  });
  es.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
   // do stuff with `event.data`
   console.log(event.data);
  });
  es.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
   console.log('event source error', event)
  });

Comment: As mentioned at previous comment, have not tried angular2.

Comment: @guest271314 ohk thanks for your help

Comment: @guest271314 hi in EventSource.js line no. 19 this.readyState is comming as undefined and also line no. 127 EventSource.prototype is not called. Do you have any idea related to this ?

Comment: No. Would again suggest filing an issue at polyfill repo with accompanying description and code to reproduce issue